# Confidence interval of a random variable

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, confidence-interval

Given $Θ$ is an unknown, and $X$~$U(Θ-0.5,Θ+0.5)$

Is $[X-2,X+2]$ an 80% interval?

Apparently, yes it is:

$$P(X-2≤Θ≤X+2)=P(Θ-2≤X≤Θ+2)=1$$

The transition from $P(X-2≤Θ≤X+2)$ to $P(Θ-2≤X≤Θ+2)$ is straightforward.

After rearranging the inequality in terms of $Θ$, how does $P(Θ-2≤X≤Θ+2)=1$?

Is it okay to assume continuous uniform distribution?

I mean, $Θ$ can be any value between the intervals with infinite precision of decimal places.

Anyways, after applying the formula provided by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution#Example_1._Using_the_Uniform_Cumulative_Distribution_Function%5B5%5D), this is what I get

$$P(Θ-2≤X≤Θ+2)=\frac{(Θ+2)-(Θ-2)}{(Θ+0.5)-(Θ-0.5)}=4≠1$$

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: $[X−2,X+2]$ is not an $80\%$ interval here - it obviously has a $100\%$ chance of containing $\Theta$ since $|X-\Theta|\le 0.5$.  Meanwhile your Wikipedia formula is for subintervals of a uniform distribution, not for intervals which overlap the ends

Comment: Yes @Henry you are right, sorry I did not specify that $P(Θ-2≤X≤Θ+2)=1≥0.8$ like you said a 100% chance. I cannot seem to find a formula for intervals which overlap the ends, could you point it out? Thanks

Comment: Suppose $a<b$ and $c\le d$.  Then if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$ I suspect you may have  $\mathbb P(X  \in [c,d]) =\dfrac{\min(d,\max(b,c))-\max(c,\min(a,d))}{b-a}$

Comment: I don't entirely get how $P(Θ-2≤X≤Θ+2)=1$ according to you @Henry "since $|−Θ|≤0.5$". I understand that logically $|−Θ|≤0.5$ is a much smaller range than $|−Θ|≤2$ so the value of $Θ$ must be within said range 100%. But what if $a$ is unknown that is $|−Θ|≤a$? Could you please explain how to derive this procedurally?

Comment: My last comment is probably redundant, I didn't see you already commented @Henry

Comment: Once again, @Henry thank you so much for your help. The formula you provided is exactly what I was looking for; I find it a pity that many courses don't provide that level of detail. It might be worth mentioning that whilst I was trying to figure this out, I found that the normal distribution returned very accurate approximations. That is, after calculating $µ$ and $σ^2$ of $$~$(Θ−0.5,Θ+0.5)$, the corresponding error function yielded $erf(2\sqrt[2]{6})≈1$ which is basically equal to $(Θ−2≤≤Θ+2)$.

Comment: The error function has nothing to do with this

Comment: Yeah, after all it's $$~$(Θ−0.5,Θ+0.5)$ instead of $$~$N(0,1)$